# JavaFX custom node creation

Tags: javafx, fxml

I tried creating my own custom node, but I miserably failed somehow.
It always throws me an error when I try to run the controller/scene.
This is my class representing the custom node

```
package com.lollookup.scene.customcontrol;

import com.lollookup.scene.data.ChampionInfoData;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import javax.xml.soap.Text;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * @author Yasin
 */
public class ChampionInfo extends Pane {

    @FXML
    private ImageView championImage;

    @FXML
    private Text KDA;

    @FXML
    private Text winRate;

    @FXML
    private Text masteryScore;

    @FXML
    private Text masteryLevel;

    public ChampionInfo() {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("championinfo.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setData(ChampionInfoData championInfoData) {
        this.championImage.setImage(new Image(championInfoData.getUrl()));
        this.KDA.setTextContent(championInfoData.getKDA());
        this.winRate.setTextContent(championInfoData.getWinRate());
        this.masteryScore.setTextContent(championInfoData.getMasteryScore());
        this.masteryLevel.setTextContent(championInfoData.getMasteryLevel());
    }

}
```

And this is my fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="84.0" prefWidth="238.0" type="Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.lollookup.scene.customcontrol.ChampionInfo">
   <children>
      <Separator layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="238.0" />
      <HBox prefHeight="84.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="championImage" fitHeight="72.0" fitWidth="66.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </ImageView>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Text fx:id="KDA" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="kda">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Text>
                  <Text fx:id="winRate" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="winRate" />
                  <Text fx:id="masteryLevel" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="champLevel" />
                  <Text fx:id="masteryScore" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="champScore" />
               </children>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Separator layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="238.0" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

My problem now is that somehow I can't really start/implement the custom node.
So no matter if I create a Scene like this:

```
    package com.lollookup.scene.customcontrol;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @author Yasin
 */
public class ChampionInfoExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        //ChampionInfo championInfo = new ChampionInfo(new ChampionInfoData("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150", "1:1", "50%", "0", "1"));
        ChampionInfo championInfo = new ChampionInfo();
        //championInfo.setData(new ChampionInfoData("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150", "1:1", "50%", "0", "1"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(championInfo));
        stage.setTitle("Custom Control");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

or instantiate it like that:
Stream.of(championData).forEach(p -> championDataContainer.getChildren().add(new ChampionInfo()));

This is what is being thrown:

```
    Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.setURL(URLStreamHandler.java:537)
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:304)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:67)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:615)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1222)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1212)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:240)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:250)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:601)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:599)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:598)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:623)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:352)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:341)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:313)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:227)
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:154)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2472)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at com.lollookup.scene.customcontrol.ChampionInfo.<init>(ChampionInfo.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

What should I do?
I'd appreciate any kind of assistance
Thanks

Edit:
After debugging, I kinda found out why it was null. Had nothing to do with the codes given. Thank you StackOverflow!

Comment: When you create a `new ChampionInfo()`, the constructor loads the FXML file. The FXML file has a `fx:controller` attribute which causes the `FXMLLoader` to create a new `ChampionInfo` instance. The constructor for that `ChampionInfo` instance loads the FXML file, which has a `fx:controller` attribute that causes the `FXMLLoader` to create a new `ChampionInfo` instance... I think you get the idea. The way to define a custom control with FXML is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components).

Comment: You assigning the controller in the fxml file. fx:controller="com.lollookup.scene.customcontrol.ChampionInfo You should not do this.

Comment: Oh, my god. I didn't realize that, thank you for clearing me up. But now all my fields are null (although I assign the controller with setController). See edit as reference